# Page Type with Category Link

Tags: categories, permalinks, tags

I have a custom-page type "page-clients.php" which loads category of "clients".

**Example:  http://website.com/clients**
(all clients-working)

**Example:  http://website.com/clients/9** 
(sub category (tagId=9) > corporate - working)

However, when I try to use the sub-category name 'corporate' is does not work

**Example:  http://website.com/clients/corporate**
(NOT WORKING) Page not found Error

The query is coded as:

```
$clientCatArray = array(9,10,11,12,13);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category__in' => $clientCatArray,
```

);

How can I get the sub-category name working just like the id is working?

Comment: How exactly is your page-clients.php loading the categories in? Is your query looking out for ID's as opposed to slugs?

Comment: @DanBeckett code snippet added to question. Thanks

Comment: You cannot have subpages with those slugs. It interferes with the template hierarhy.  Use the page template as a index page to list all your categories. Then link and use category.php to display the single categories

Comment: @PieterGoosen I want to be able to send a link as `http://website.com/clients/corporate` NOT `http://website.com/category/clients/corporate/` is this possible?